# Converting/Processing JSON list into dictionary (or other structure)

Tags: python, json, validation, dictionary, data-cleaning

Seems totally easy but having a braincramp trying to get this done. I have an API request the receives the following as a response.

```
[{u'text': u'test ASDF', u'ts': u'1453578721.000005', u'user': u'U0K7P5EBG', u'team': u'T0K7K1KEH', u'type': u'message', u'channel': u'D0K7P9MCJ'}]
```

OR

```
[{u'type': u'hello'}]
```

I want to process that response, checking for keys, data, etc. I've attempted to create dict() from the list, attempted to load as json() and I can't seem to get the data into a format that is easy to process.

```
>>> a = [{u'text': u'test ASDF', u'ts': u'1453578721.000005', u'user': u'U0K7P5EBG', u'team': u'T0K7K1KEH', u'type': u'message', u'channel': u'D0K7P9MCJ'}]
>>> dict(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
>>> a = [{u'text': u'test ASDF', u'ts': u'1453578721.000005', u'user': u'U0K7P5EBG', u'team': u'T0K7K1KEH', u'type': u'message', u'channel': u'D0K7P9MCJ'}]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> a[0]
{u'text': u'test ASDF', u'ts': u'1453578721.000005', u'user': u'U0K7P5EBG', u'team': u'T0K7K1KEH', u'type': u'message', u'channel': u'D0K7P9MCJ'}
```

I want the data in a simple format like d[k] where I can check for existing of keys and get their values. A dictionary. How can I get this data formatted properly?

```
d["text"] -> would yield 'test ASDF'
etc
```

TIA

Comment: But you've already done it: `a[0]`? Isn't it what you want? Thanks.

Comment: I was missing one stap as Kyle pointed out. a[0] is what I wanted, but I then wanted to select a key to output the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON object you have is a list of dictionaries (one at least), so you simply need to grab the first element of the list.

```
d = a[0]
d['text']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. This should work:

```
dict(a[0])
```